# Get hostname by folder/file properties

Tags: python, file, winapi

I have a path to file/folder in a local network and I need to see its user hostname or IP.
I used existing code like:

```
FILENAME  = r'Y:\\Projects\\Username\\test_json.js'

sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity (FILENAME, win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
owner_sid = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner ()
name, domain, typ = win32security.LookupAccountSid ('server', owner_sid)
```

Finally I get a pc login name
But is it possible to get a network name or ip of folder\file user?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the UNC path from a network drive with `win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName`. And the hostname is included.

```
import win32wnet
import sys

print(win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName(FILENAME, 1))
```

UNC path is like:

```
\\hostname\sharename\filepath
```

You can get the ip address with

```
import socket
ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
print(ip)
```

Comment: unfortunatley it does not give me username of a folder. Just a full path to a file with parent network folder.

Comment: So, you want a username or the hostname? `WNetGetUniversalName(FILENAME, 1)` will give a UNC path like : `\\hostname\\sharename\\path`